# How to enable custom text to hibernate logs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, log4j2

We are using spring boot application using jpa.

We have added custom trace identifier I'd which is appended to all the logs to identify per request.

Is there any way to append this string to hibernate logs as well.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j2s [Thread Context](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) is what you are looking for

```
ThreadContext.put("traceId", yourTraceIdentifier); 

// invoke whatever
// which will, in turn, invoke Hibernate
// which will do some logging

ThreadContext.clear();
```

In your log format, you then need to specify that you want the data included in the log. You can do it with the format `%X`.